# What could cause an Android app to run slow on an identical device to one which it runs fast on?

Tags: performance, android

I, and a few other of my Android app users, run a Galaxy Nexus. Most of us find the app to be blazing fast, but a couple are reporting that it is unusably slow ***also on a Galaxy Nexus***. I'm shocked to hear them tell me that the buttons, scrolling, etc. are all slow. The main view of the app is a `ListView` containing many images, textviews, etc. In fact, you can check out [the app for free on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.streamified.streamified) if you feel like digging deeper. I'm trying to compile a checklist of what might cause this issue.

Here's what I have so far:

- Low memory
- Low disk space
- Uncaught errors
- Rooted device (?)

Any other ideas?

More importantly, is there any way to detect (or even adjust for!) potential problems?

Answer (score 0):

Some other things:

- CPU Usage (monitor via an app like WatchDog (it's free)); it mightn't be your app that's the problem
- Android version.
- Connection speed (Wi-Fi vs 4G vs 3G vs 1x)
- Carrier (since they like to flash their own custom ROMs)

AFAIK Android version and connection speed are exposed by the SDK, not sure about CPU usage or carrier.

Of the errors you listed, I think that low memory would be the most likely factor.

If I were you, I'd create a function that would collect as much of this information as possible and send it to your email (or someplace).  Then, have some way for the user to call this function (e.g. in the settings menu or someplace like that).

Granted this is all just intuition as an end-user, I have little experience debugging deployed  apps from the coding side.